# Magento 2 - New Tax rule page showing "require is not defined" error in console

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, tax, requirejs

When I try to add new tax rule I am getting "require is not defined" error in console which cause properly loading issue for Tax Rate, Customer Tax Class and Product Tax Class field (see below screenshot). Any idea why I am getting this error?

[image]

Comment: is this only on that page? Any other pages? Have you tried deleting cache and generated folders and then compile and deploy?

Comment: Magento version number?

Comment: @KalvinKlien That is the only page. Magento version in 2.4.1. I have other magento site with same version which working fine. Not sure what happened with this one.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to you, but I experienced this issue and was able to resolve it by disabling a Cloudflare feature called Rocket Loader.

The 3 require errors you're seeing are part of the html sent to the browser, but not handled by Rocket Loader. As such they execute before require is available.

I haven't seen this cause any other issues anywhere in Magento so it's a strange one.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off Rocket Loader on Cloudflare worked for me. I was having the same issue on 2.4.4.